# Custom ActionBar Drop Down menu

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, actionbarsherlock

I found this app! [All events in the city](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amitech.allevents&hl=ru)

It has big drop down item with custom layout inside!
[link with photo inside, i cant add photo here!!!](http://www.sendspace.com/file/9bz80r)

Maybe that is

```
ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST
```

with only one item inside?

I realy dont know how to do something like this! Please i realy need help!

Comment: Simply looks like an `Activity` (with transparent/translucent theme) or a `(Dialog)Fragment` over the top to me.

Comment: its the Navigation Drawer sliding from right . . you can find it here . .<a>http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html</a>